# How to choose between 32 bit or 64 bit version of a package?

Tags: chocolatey

When I install `choco install notepadplusplus`  it installs 64 bit of Notepad++ and it causes issues (there no package manager for 64 bit of npp)

Is there any way to specifically choose 32 bit or 64 bit of an installation package? I expect there should be a switch for choco install, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was missing the `forcex86` switch:

> --x86, --forcex86  ForceX86 - Force x86 (32bit) installation on 64
>   bit systems. Defaults to     false.

Here is the full list of Options and Switches.
https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsInstall#options-and-switches