# How To Determine Bitness of Choclatey Package

Tags: installation, chocolatey, 32-vs-64-bit

Looking through the help, I see that the install defaults to your processor architecture; but if you have a 64-bit OS and only 32-bit package is available, it will fall back.  So how can you tell which one you're getting (ideally without installing)?  Also, will x86 package names always end in `x86`?

Using `--checksum64` somehow might work, but I haven't been able to get that to work yet.  FWIW, there's a [force x86 install](https://superuser.com/questions/1167112/how-to-choose-between-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-a-package) option, but there doesn't seem to be one to force x64.

Comment: Just a question.. Why does it matter?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: If you want to load multi-gigabyte files into RAM, a 32-bit application might not work for you. In such a case, you'll want the 64-bit version of that application instead. Therefore, you might want to make sure Chocolatey is able to install the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't love this answer, but it's a start.  Run `choco install [package]`, and it will download the binar(y|ies) and pause to ask if you want to actually install them.  I'm not sure of the exact location it will drop them, but I just searched my AppDAta for the package.

```
Directory of C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\NuGetScratch\0b0d34f0-3921-4e7b-8997-68b940ecb090\fh12npqr.j5j\tools

09/19/2019  10:36 AM        41,561,144 vcxsrv-64.1.20.5.1.installer_x64.exe
09/19/2019  10:36 AM        40,632,035 vcxsrv.1.20.5.1.installer_x32.exe
               2 File(s)     82,193,179 bytes
```

Fortunately for me, I can clearly see that I have both options.  If only one is there, I guess you just have to probe the binary to see what it is.